# Inappropriate migration to Arduino?

Tags: discussion

I don't see a good reason that [this](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/32668) question was migrated to Arduino.  Yes, it was posted by a clueless ardweenie who showed more of a Paint drawing than a schematic, and there was a arduino envolved, but the question itself had nothing to do with the arduinoness.

Both Andy and I posted answers that got several upvotes, and the OP even accepted one of them.

If I had known this question was going to get banished to the kiddy table, I wouldn't have bothered writing a answer.  I usually don't put much effort into things that will likely be moved or closed.  I thought this one might get closed due to bad schematic, but it never occurred to me that it might get migrated.

What does the community think of this migration?  Or perhaps the mod that did the migrating can defend the action or explain the special circumstance that the rest of use aren't aware of?

I just noticed that the edit history got wiped out.  This question might have started with no schematic, but certainly went thru at least 3 versions while I was watching.

Comment: The edit history exists only on the EE version of the question. You have to follow the link back from the Arduino version.

Comment: Nick is absolutely notorious for this (and not even only to the Arduino site, though he will basically migrate anything that merely contains that word), why his moderator powers haven't been revoked over it is one of the great mysteries of the Internet.

Comment: @Chris: That's rather harsh on Nick.  Disagreeing with a user about a few migrations doesn't make someone a bad mod.  Nick does a lot of good cleanup around here.  It's OK to disagree and discuss issues, but that should always be done respectfully and with a open mind at least until all the facts are in.  Don't lose sight of the fact that the mods do a lot of janitorial work behind the scenes on our behalf.  We get to do more of the fun stuff with less hassles as a result.

Comment: @OlinLathrop - it's not a "few" it's a *constant* steam of *egregiously* wrong calls that can only come from a willful decision to disregard system-wide rules about migration.  And it's a sort of misbehavior that is extremely hard for even other moderators to clean up after.  He ran out of excuses long ago!

Comment: Seriously, there can be no doubt that Nick Alexeev has absolutely no willingess to accept the principles of the stack exchange system  - consider, for example http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/32887/can-i-get-patent-from-device-which-was-made-with-open-source-parts which is not an Arduino question, but merely a wrong-everywhere question.

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, I agree that the migration was inappropriate. The question is mainly about a microcontroller switching its own power.

Comment: Seriously Dave, the time has long past to disagree with Nick.  The only question worth asking is what, **you** and the other moderators, are going to *do* about Nick's unrepentant misbehavior.

Comment: @ChrisStratton probably ignore it like they ignore Op's unrelenting rudeness towards anyone he deems below him.